# Finding the Mathematica package for time series

Tags: packages, documentation, time-series

I'm studying time series. Searching at internet I found [this pdf file](http://media.wolfram.com/documents/TimeSeriesDocumentation.pdf) with a lot a useful information and examples about time series.

I want to know if some one knows how to get the required package indicated in page number 5 (TimeSeries.m) of the above pdf file.

Comment: [`TimeSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) is included in *Mathematica* and does not need to be loaded with `Needs`.  That PDF documentation link is from 2007; ten years ago.  Use the documentation from in *Mathematica* by pressing F1. It has updated guides and tutorials built in.

Comment: TimeSeries is obsolescent add-on package for very old versions of Mathematica. Most of its functionality incorporated into recent Mathematica distributions.